Blinking issue with multiple 7-Segment Displays on Arduino Uno
I'm working on a project using an Arduino Uno to control six separate 7-segment display modules. Each display consists of four digits, and I want to show different numbers on each module. The final goal is to display data coming from an RS485 communication system on these displays, but right now I'm just trying to get the basic display functionality working.
Display setup:
6 separate displays
Each display shows 4 digits (e.g., 0000, 1234, 9999, etc.)
For example:
Display 1: XXXX
Display 2: XXXX
Display 3: XXXX
Display 4: XXXX
Display 5: XXXX
Display 6: XXXX
Where "X" is a single digit (0-9).
Code attempts:
I started with this basic code to display numbers on a single module, and it worked fine:
int dataPin = 11;   // DS (Data Pin)
int clockPin = 13;  // SH_CP (Clock Pin)
int latchPin = 10;  // ST_CP (Latch Pin)

void setup() {
    pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
    // Shift in three zeros for the first three registers (turn them off)
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, 0b00000110);  // 1st register
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, 0b00000000);  // 2nd register
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, 0b00000000);  // 3rd register
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, 0b01111101);  // "1" on the last register
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);

    delay(1000);
}

This code worked well with one display but when I attached all six and tried this below code
#include <Arduino.h>

// Define shared pins for all shift registers
const int latchPin = 10;
const int clockPin = 13;
const int dataPin = 2;

// Segment patterns for digits 0-9
const byte segmentData[] = {
  0b00111111, // 0
  0b00000110, // 1
  0b01011011, // 2
  0b01001111, // 3
  0b01100110, // 4
  0b01101101, // 5
  0b01111101, // 6
  0b00000111, // 7
  0b01111111, // 8
  0b01101111  // 9
};

// Number of digits per display
const int numDigits = 4;

// Number of displays
const int numDisplays = 6;

// Array to hold the data to be displayed
byte displayBuffer[numDigits * numDisplays] = {0};

void setup() {
  // Set shared pins as output
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // Update the buffer with the numbers to be displayed
  updateDisplayBuffer(3030, 6);  // Update sixth display
  updateDisplayBuffer(2021, 5);  // Update fifth display
  updateDisplayBuffer(1015, 4);  // Update fourth display
  updateDisplayBuffer(7893, 3);  // Update third display
  updateDisplayBuffer(4564, 2);  // Update second display
  updateDisplayBuffer(1238, 1);  // Update first display

  // Send the buffered data to the displays
  updateDisplays();

  delay(1000);  // Wait 1 second before updating again
}

// Function to update the buffer for a specific display
void updateDisplayBuffer(int number, int display) {
  // Calculate the starting position in the buffer for the specific display
  int startShiftRegister = (display - 1) * numDigits;

  // Flag to indicate if a non-zero digit has been encountered
  bool hasNonZeroDigit = false;

  // Store the digits in the buffer from most significant to least significant
  for (int i = numDigits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int digit = number / pow(10, i);
    digit %= 10;
    // Suppress leading zeros
    if (digit != 0 || hasNonZeroDigit || i == 0) {
      hasNonZeroDigit = true;
      displayBuffer[startShiftRegister + (numDigits - 1 - i)] = segmentData[digit];
    } else {
      // If it's a leading zero and hasn't encountered a non-zero digit, turn off the segments
      displayBuffer[startShiftRegister + (numDigits - 1 - i)] = 0b00000000;  // Turn off all segments
    }
  }
}

// Function to update all displays at once
void updateDisplays() {
  // Prepare to send data to all shift registers
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);

  // Shift out all data from the buffer in reverse order
  for (int i = (numDigits * numDisplays) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, displayBuffer[i]);
  }

  // Latch the data to display the updated numbers
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}


The numbers are displayed on each module, but they are blinking. I can’t figure out why this is happening. I haven’t integrated the RS485 data into the code yet—just trying to get basic display functionality to work.
Can anyone help me figure out why the displays are blinking and how to fix it?
Display specification:

Display module has only 10 pins first 5 are Data, CLK, STRB, 12v, GND and second 5 are QS1,CLK,STRB, 12V, GND.
IC present on display is CD4094B (Shift Register)
NSK ELECTRONICS: 7SEG 4 Digit Display 2.2" with SIPO based 3 Wire Control

this is the link of the video in which the flickering effect is seen
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10kunwTadQf1bHoDo_Ueg9NO9sBcVz4fL/view

You have six displays with separate data pins but common clock and latch pins.
Each time you update one display by using correct data pin for that display and use the global clock pin to load data bits and global latch pin pin to store the sent data, you update the five other displays by clocking in garbage data and latching it.
You can fix it by not doing that and there are many different ways how to not do that. Change the code to send correct data to all displays before latching, or change the hardware so you can send data and latch it to one display only.

Hi, thanks for your suggestion. However, using separate clock and latch pins for each display would take up too many pins, which I want to avoid. I've modified the code and updated it in my question, and while it has significantly reduced the flickering, there is still a noticeable flicker effect. Could you help me resolve this issue? I've also uploaded a video along with the updated code

@Muhammed I can't figure out anything different in the code that is able to update one individual display or all at once - you see to use one clock, one data, and one latch pin for all displays, is this right?

Yes, you are right. I am using a single set of clock, data, and latch pins for all the displays, and they are connected in a daisy chain configuration. Since I'm new to this kind of work, I'm finding it challenging to fully understand what you're suggesting. Could you please clarify your explanation?

@Muhammed But you said what pins the displays have and they can't be put into daisy chain based on that info. If you don't tell how you wired them, I can't say what's wrong.

the display has a total of 10 pins first 5 are Data, CLK, STRB, 12v, GND and the second 5 are QS1, CLK, STRB, 12V, and GND. So I connect the Data, CLK, and STRB of the first display to Arduino UNO and I attach the second display Data, CLK, STRB, 12v, and GND to QS1, CLK, STRB, 12V, and GND of the first display this is how I am connecting in daisy chain pattern
